# Simple fade-out animation for a string on canvas, android

Tags: android, animation, custom-controls, android-animation, android-canvas

I have a custom view extending from `View` with lots of text drawn at different angles and I want a particular string to decrease its alpha value to a certain level once, after first start. Any suggestion or snippet would be appreciated :)

`postInvalidateDelayed(...)` doesn't seem to work for this task.

Comment: What version of Android are you targeting? Honeycomb and up have an animation framework you can use to accomplish this.

Comment: uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" , target is 2.3.3. I know about that framework but I am one step below :P.

Comment: `postInvalidateDelayed(...)` is working now. There was a mistake in the correct measurement of text bounds to be faded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mistake in the correct measurement of vertical text bounds to be faded. Here is my `onDraw` method

```
Paint myPaint = new Paint();
myPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#" + colorAlpha + "3AA6D0"));// initially colorAlpha is ff
Rect r = new Rect();
char[] a = "Hello World".toCharArray();
datePaint.getTextBounds(a, 0, a.length, r);// get the bound of the text, I was not calculating this correctly
canvas.drawText("Hello World", 0, 0, myPaint);// draw the text

int colorValue = Integer.parseInt(colorAlpha, 16);
    colorValue -= 20;// decrease alpha value for next call to onDraw method by postInvalidateDelayed
if (colorValue > 40) {
        colorAlpha = Integer.toHexString(colorValue);


 // this will create the effect of fade out animation
 // because each call to onDraw method is at the difference of 50 millisecond delay 
 // and in each call we are decreasing alpha value by 20.
        postInvalidateDelayed(50, r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility might be to create two views, inside of a `FrameLayout` that overlap each other.  One view would contain all the static strings, the other the string you want to animate.  Then it would be a simple matter of adding an alpha animation to the animated view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <package.MyNonAnimatedView
        android:id="@+id/nonAnimatedView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <package.MyAnimatedView
        android:id="@+id/animatedView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And for an animation you would attach to the animated view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="100" />
```

From within your activity's `onCreate(Bundle)` method, you can call `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Context, int)` to load the animation from the xml resource and attach it to the animated view (provided you give it an id).

Comment: Nice:) But these two views are related and I have to separate them by using interfaces etc just for simple animation to use this approach.

Comment: Hmm...If the two views are similar enough in how they create the strings, you could potentially just instantiate the same view twice in the above xml code.  Interacting between the two views (if necessary) via the activity is easy enough.  The simplest approach is to completely separate the view code from the animation code, but animating a view as described above will animate the entire view, not just one part of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to your activity that can send [messages](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) at a specified interval.  When your activity receives a callback from the handler, it can notify the view to update the parts that you want to change.

An example:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity implements Handler.Callback {

    int mDelay = 100; // Update interval (milliseconds).
    Handler mHandler = new Handler(this);
    private Runnable mEvent = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mEvent, mDelay);
            Message message = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            // Add arguments to message, if required.
            mHandler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
        // Your view update code.
    }

    private void start() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mEvent, mDelay);
    }

    private void stop() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mEvent);
    }
}
```

Calling `start()` starts the handler, `stop()` stops it.  Determining when to stop the handler will probably be in the `handleMessage(Message)` code.

Comment: This approach can also be used but I somehow got the method  `postInvalidateDelayed(...)` working. There was a mistake in the correct measurement of vertical text bounds to be faded.

Comment: I'd recommend posting the solution you got to work and then accepting it as the answer.